# WordPress theme development - force browser not to cache website

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am learning web and WordPress theme development. Is there a way to force the browser to NOT use cache version of the website when I have have made changes to the HTML, CSS, JS files.

Answer (score 0):

We can let the browser know that we have made changes to the CSS/JS by changing the version of the file:

```php
function pr_scripts_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '20200902', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles');
```

as you see `20200902` that is the version, simply increase it by 1 after we have some change.